# regex to add a limit of 10 digits with decimal value having no limit

Tags: php, regex

I want to apply a validation where I need a limit of 10 digits on value but the value after decimal has no limit.

Like this
`1000000000.2121`
The value before decimal should be less than 10 digits.
I am trying this regex
`^(10|\d)(\.\d{1,2})?$`
 But By this, I only add decimal digits with a limit of two. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try changing it to `d{1,10}`?

Comment: JayBlanchard yes, I tried but what if someone adds more than 10 digits after a decimal? This will again throw validation.

Comment: its a number `if (v < 9E9)` would suffice

Comment: @Naina Please provide a battery of values and your desired evaluation of each.

Comment: You have receive 4 answers -- all of which interpret your needs differently.  This is the sign of an Unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

If the total should be no more than 10, and the digit can not start with a comma, you could assert not 11 digits and keep the `\d+` to match 1 or more digits.

```
^(?!(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){11})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that what is on the right is not

  - `(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){11}` Match 11 times any char except a newline followed by a digit
- `)` Close lookahead.
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match a dot and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QpqlCp/1)

Comment: ```required|numeric|regex:^(?!(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){11})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$'```  gives an error saying preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\\'

Comment: Can you give this a check over [here](https://regex101.com/r/i6JaWX/3) @TheFourthBird? Not my dv btw

Comment: @mickmackusa I think the OP want to match 10 digits in total including the decimal part due to this line `Like this 1000000000.2121 The value before decimal should be less than 10 digits.`

Comment: Even if that is the desired rule, your answer is incorrectly evaluating several of the inputs in my above commented demo of your pattern. Maybe we should vote to close as Unclear.  The OP seems to have gone away.

Comment: @JvdV My assumption is that the total should be no more than 10 digits. If that is not the case, then my answer is wrong.

Comment: @mickmackusa The values that you use have 11 digits. The one with the leading dot I have not anticipated, because the OP's pattern starts with 1+ digits. https://regex101.com/r/V38F4U/1

Comment: Ah, a different take on what's asked. Haven't thought in that direction.

Comment: @Naina Try `preg_match('/^(?!(?:[^\d\r\n]*\d){11})\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/m', $string, $matches)` See https://3v4l.org/9c50K

Comment: Do you know about `preg_grep()` @The ? https://ideone.com/sB3Otf

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes I do, but if you read carefully, the first comment of the OP is about `preg_match()` that is why I used that in the example.

Comment: That is just what the framework is executing her rule with.

Comment: Well, I have not idea what the framework is. I see that in the comments by the OP. What are you trying to accomplish with your comments?

Comment: If you agree that the question requirements are foggy, please vote to close as Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> The value before decimal should be less than 10 digits

This pattern permits zero to 9 digits then optionally allows a decimal point followed by unlimited digits.

If your requirement is to have at least one digit before the decimal, then change `{0-9}` to `{1,9}`.

If your requirement is to have between zero and ten digits before the decimal, then change `{0,9}` to `{0,10}`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oZ8sB))

```
$tests = [
    '12345678901',
    '1234567890',
    '123456789',
    '1234567890.1',
    '1234567.8901',
    '1234.5678901',
    '1.2345678901',
    '.12345678901',
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    var_export([$test, (bool)preg_match('~^\d{0,9}(?:\.\d+)?$~', $test)]);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '12345678901',
  1 => false,
)
array (
  0 => '1234567890',
  1 => false,
)
array (
  0 => '123456789',
  1 => true,
)
array (
  0 => '1234567890.1',
  1 => false,
)
array (
  0 => '1234567.8901',
  1 => true,
)
array (
  0 => '1234.5678901',
  1 => true,
)
array (
  0 => '1.2345678901',
  1 => true,
)
array (
  0 => '.12345678901',
  1 => true,
)
```

Comment: According to the question's logic your answer is not right. read this ( I want to apply a validation where I need a limit of 10 digits on value but the value after decimal has no limit).

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will work for <= 10 digits to value before the dot and any number of digits after the dot.

```
$b = preg_match("!^\d{1,10}(\.\d*)?$!",109.9);
```

Comment: Would you explain please?

Comment: Your pattern matches an 11-digit integer.  This is in breach of the required logic.

Comment: Now your answer is almost my answer except it allows 10 digits before the decimal point AND it will match `0.`.

Answer (score 0):

You are stating two things (and not showing a lot of examples to work with):

- "The value before decimal should be less than 10 digits"
- "I need a limit of 10 digits on value but the value after decimal has no limit"

Which one is it? I went with the first assumption where there cannot be more than 9 digits but there must be at least one. Also for number validity I thought it would make sense to *only* start with a single zero or non at all:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,8})(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i6JaWX/4)

---

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?:` - 1st Non-capture group.

  - `0|[1-9]\d{0,8}` - a single zero **or** a single digit between 1-9 followed by zero to 8 more digits to keep under 10 digits total.
- `)` - Closing 1st non-capture group.
- `(?:` - 2nd Non-capture group.

  - `\.\d+` - A literal dot followed by one or more digits.
- `)` - Close 2nd non-capture group.
- `?` - Make 2nd non-capture group optional.
- `$` - End string ancor.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Note:** This can be simplified if you allow numbers to start with a dot.